# Shortcut syntax for clearing JavaScript closures

Tags: javascript, closures, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Based on the [chaining rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387247/in-javascript-is-chained-assignment-okay) for JavaScript, I have been using the following shortcut syntax to [clear closure variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550253/memory-leaks-and-closures-in-javascript-when-and-why):

```
//Clear closure variables....
a=b=c=d=e=f=null;
```

For context, the situation might be:

```
// variables a,b,c,d,e are defined somewhere up here.

doSomething(function callback() {
   // Do a bunch of work with a,b,c,d,e
   // Now clear variables
   a=b=c=d=e=null;
});
```

Is this a reasonable way to set a bunch of variables to `null` concisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it totally is.

<sub>Altough I prefer spaces around assignment operators.</sub>

<sub>And you hardly ever really need to null out closure variables. If you work on such advanced stuff, chained assignments are a minor concern.</sub>